# Getting errors with images in php on some occasions

Tags: php

So I have 4 images, all named cover.png in 4 different folders, theyre named 1,2,3,4

I needed an image resizing system that took 3 bits of info, w (width), h (height) and url

Then this php file would resize the image, save it, display it, then delete it, it worked with images 1, 2 and 3. But failed on 4. I got around 8 errors

Here is the php file after taking width, height and url.

`$url` is the url of the original image

`$width` is the width of the new image

`$height` is the height of the new image

The first line here is line 8

```
    $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($url);
    $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
    $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
    $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
    ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, 
    $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
    ImageJPEG($images_fin,"./temp.png");
    ImageDestroy($images_fin);

    $filename = "./temp.png";
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    imagejpeg($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
    unlink($filename)
```

The errors are as follows:

```
( ! ) Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x52 0x49 in B:\wamp64\www\img\index.php on line 8
```

```
( ! ) Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): '/music/4/cover.png' is not a valid JPEG file in B:\wamp64\www\img\index.php on line 8
```

```
( ! ) Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in B:\wamp64\www\img\index.php on line 9
```

```
( ! ) Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in B:\wamp64\www\img\index.php on line 10
```

```
( ! ) Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, bool given in B:\wamp64\www\img\index.php on line 13
```

```
( ! ) Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at B:\wamp64\www\img\index.php:10) in B:\wamp64\www\img\index.php on line 19
```

All i see is this: (where an image should be)

```
����JFIF``��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality ��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?���(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(���
```

Comment: All of the above are warnings not errors. So there might be some logical issue with the code. If you can put it the code where you are calling these 4 files that would help

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen That is all the code, its all there.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen 

As i said, it works perfectly when i call image 3, image 4 returns an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from the error message:

> imagecreatefromjpeg(): '/music/4/cover.png' is not a valid JPEG file

You are trying to read `png` image using `imagecreatefromjpeg`. To read `png` images use [imageCreateFromPng](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) instead.

Here is example for more generic solution:

```
<?php
function imageCreateFromAny($filepath) {
    $type = exif_imagetype($filepath); // [] if you don't have exif you could use getImageSize()
    $allowedTypes = array(
        1,  // [] gif
        2,  // [] jpg
        3,  // [] png
        6   // [] bmp
    );
    if (!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)) {
        return false;
    }
    switch ($type) {
        case 1 :
            $im = imageCreateFromGif($filepath);
        break;
        case 2 :
            $im = imageCreateFromJpeg($filepath);
        break;
        case 3 :
            $im = imageCreateFromPng($filepath);
        break;
        case 6 :
            $im = imageCreateFromBmp($filepath);
        break;
    }   
    return $im; 
}
```

Souce: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#110547